# Undefined class constant 'FOLLOW_SYMLINKS

Tags: symfony

after installing symfony 2.6 and when executing an error message is displayed:

```
FatalErrorException in DirectoryResource.php line 82:
Error: Undefined class constant 'FOLLOW_SYMLINKS'
```

the error is in the bundle: kriswallsmith

Please help me.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class constant, FOLLOW_SYMLINKS, is part of the [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php), which according to the PHP.net manual page, was added in 5.3.1 and also 5.2.11.  At least version 5.3.9 is usually recommended or required by various frameworks because of various issues in prior versions.

The package is "[kriswallsmith/assetic](https://packagist.org/packages/kriswallsmith/assetic)"

Answer (score 1):

Which versio of PHP are you running under? `5.2`?

This sounds awfully similar to this issue report: https://github.com/caefer/sfImageTransformExtraPlugin/issues/5